# Maximage with Cycle - 'Speed' option is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I am trying to use Maximage jQuery plugin with the Cycle option.

However, changing the speed option to 6000 seems to make no difference. It fades very quickly.

```
$('#maximage').maximage({
    cycleOptions: {
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 12000,
        speed: 6000
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M6AtC/

Is there any known bug to this and workaround? Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Mikey.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what it is!

If you're in a CSS3 transition capable browser, the plugin will take its effect speed from the CSS provided with the Maximage plugin.

If you want something like:

```
speed: 3000
```

You also need to change your CSS like so:

```
transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
```

Hope this helps someone else in future.